# Is “ça me fait rire” a correct phrase?

Tags: expressions

I don't recognise this phrase to be the same one I learnt in class is it inaccurate or should it be something else? The phrase i want in french is It makes me laugh. Thanks

Comment: That's correct. [Here it is in a dictionary](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/%C3%A7a%20me%20fait%20rire%20!). Next time please [search a little by yourself](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: sorry i just remember in class it being " ca me rire "

Comment: *Ça me rire* is broken French (~ "It me laugh.")

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is a correct sentence, although a little familiar.

Step-by-step rundown:

"Ça" is the contracted, familiar form of "cela", which means "that, it".

"me" could be placed after the verb as "moi" : "Cela fait rire moi". It is not correct french, but keeps the Subject-Verb-Object (SVO) syntax.

"faire rire" is directly translatable as "make laugh".